# In R, correlation test between two columns, for each of the groups in a third column

Tags: r

My data frame (g) contains 2 columns with continues data and other columns with categorical data. I want to test for correlations between the 2 continues variables, in different groups which are defined by a third column.
g (157X3000) look like:

```
     Geno          GDW         GN        M1     M2      M3
1 SB002XSB012 -17.1597630   52.31961    G/G    C/C     T/T
3 SB002XSB044  -3.6537657   53.81305    G/G    C/G     G/G
4 SB002XSB051  -7.8411596   58.05924    A/G    C/C     G/T
5 SB002XSB067   2.8412103   30.85074    A/G    G/G     G/T
6 SB002XSB073 -16.0789550  -10.09913    A/A    C/G     G/G
7 SB002XSB095   0.1759709   10.28837    A/A    G/G     T/T
```

I'm looking for the correlations between GDW and GN in each of the groups as defined by each M.
I tried :

```
q<- function (x) {

spl<-split(g[,2:3],x)

r<-function(x) { if ((nrow(x[[1]][1]))>2)

cor.test(x[[1]][1],x[[1]][2],use="pairwise.complete.obs")[3:4] else Na
}

cor<- sapply(spl,r)

}

all.cor<- apply(g[,4:ncol(g)],2,q)
```

and got:

```
Error in if ((nrow(x[[1]][1])) > 2) cor.test(x[[1]][1], x[[1]][2], use = "pairwise.complete.obs")[3:4] else Na : 
  argument is of length zero
```

and did'n solved it

Any ideas

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a suitable place for this kind of question. [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com) is.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you want to compute the correlations between GDW and GN for every value in the column M1 (that is, by splitting at every unique value of M1).

Using Hadley's [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/)

```
require(plyr)
# assuming the data.frame is df (Note: factor M1 if necessary)
daply(df, .(M1), function(y) cor(y$GDW, y$GN))
```

Comment: Thanks. It work for one column, but if i try to split the GDW and GN each time by different column with: q<- function (x) { daply(df, .(x), function(y) cor(y$GDW, y$GN)) }       apply(df[,4:ncol(df)],2,q)    I get Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this inside of function `r`:

```
if ((length(x[[1]]))>2)
    cor.test(x[[1]],x[[2]],use="pairwise.complete.obs")[3:4] else NA
```

`x[[1]]` is a vector, whereas `x[[1]][1]` is a single element of that vector.  You clearly want vectors for `cor.test` and not single elements.

In addition, a vector has a `length` but `nrow` is not appropriate.

The error that you get is a result of `nrow(x[[1]][1])` evaluating to `NULL`, so `nrow(x[[1]][1]) > 2` evaluates to `logical(0)`.  The argument to `if` should be a `logical` of length 1.