# In R, correlation test between two columns, for each of the groups in a third column

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In R, correlation test between two columns, for each of the groups in a third column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030697/in-r-correlation-test-between-two-columns-for-each-of-the-groups-in-a-third-co)

My data frame (g) contains 2 columns with continuous data and other columns with categorical data. I want to test for correlations between the 2 continuous variables, in different groups which are defined by a third column.
g (157X3000) look like:

```
     Geno          GDW         GN        M1     M2      M3
1 SB002XSB012 -17.1597630   52.31961    G/G    C/C     T/T
3 SB002XSB044  -3.6537657   53.81305    G/G    C/G     G/G
4 SB002XSB051  -7.8411596   58.05924    A/G    C/C     G/T
5 SB002XSB067   2.8412103   30.85074    A/G    G/G     G/T
6 SB002XSB073 -16.0789550  -10.09913    A/A    C/G     G/G
7 SB002XSB095   0.1759709   10.28837    A/A    G/G     T/T
```

I'm looking for the correlations between GDW and GN in each of the groups as defined by each M. I tried :

```
q<- function (x) {  
    spl<-split(g[,2:3],x)  
    r<-function(x) { 
        if ((nrow(x[[1]][1]))>2)  
          cor.test(x[[1]][1],x[[1]][2],use="pairwise.complete.obs")[3:4] else Na  
    }  
    cor<- sapply(spl,r)  
} 

all.cor<- apply(g[,4:ncol(g)],2,q)
```

and got:

```
Error in if ((nrow(x[[1]][1])) > 2) cor.test(x[[1]][1], x[[1]][2], use = "pairwise.complete.obs")[3:4] else Na : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Comment: See the answer that I entered to the identical question, linked above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

or if you use the `plyr` package you could say (copying Antoine's sample data)

```
library(plyr)
g <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(100, 1, 1), col2=rnorm(100, 10, 3), col3=c(rep("a", 50), rep("b", 50)))

co <- ddply(g, .(col3), function(adf) cor(adf[,1], adf[,2]))
```

to give a data.frame looking something like...

```
    col3         V1
  1    a -0.1697979
  2    b  0.1660783
```

**EDIT: adding looping for multiple columns**
**EDIT2: removing ridiculously complicated expression!**

```
library(plyr)
g <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(100, 1, 1),
            col2=rnorm(100, 10, 3),
            col3=sample(c('a','b','c'), 100, replace=TRUE),
            col4=sample(c('a','b','c'), 100, replace=TRUE),
            col5=sample(c('a','b','c'), 100, replace=TRUE),
            col6=sample(c('a','b','c'), 100, replace=TRUE))
for (i in 3:6) {
  co <- ddply(g, i, function(adf) cor(adf[,1], adf[,2]))
  names(co) <- c('variable',paste('CorCol',i, sep='-'))
  if(exists('odf')) { 
    odf <- merge(odf, co, by='variable', all=TRUE)
  } else {
    odf <- co
  } 
}
```

Results are in data.frame odf with a column for each correlation so looks like:

```
> odf
  variable    CorCol-3    CorCol-4    CorCol-5    CorCol-6
1        a  0.29596471 -0.12278082  0.02184259  0.11972933
2        b -0.11793616  0.08827011  0.11030097 -0.03682823
3        c -0.09552299  0.12951251 -0.03855727 -0.03082486
```

Comment: +1, thanks for the example with `plyr`. I really should start using it. It makes for a lot less typing.

Comment: Thanks, tried this and it works for 1 column, I want to use multiple column to define the groups. I tried: q<- function (x) {
daply(g1[,2:3], .(x),function (y) cor (y$"X11_GDW_BPH",y$"X11_GN_BPH"))
}
all.cor<- apply(g1[,4:3000],2,q)    and get error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "use multiple column" please?  Are the columns independent or can they be pasted together? e.g. paste(g[,4],g[,5],g[,6], sep='-')

Comment: I want to test each column separately, and to see how the groups in each column affect the correlation of the first 2.

Comment: Consider "accepting" my answer if you like it!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily using a `for` loop (this should work fine unless you have a very high number of levels in your categorical column).

Here is a snippet of code that should be easily adapted to your data (you only need to change the names of the columns to make them correspond to the one in your data frame):

```
g <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(100, 1, 1), col2=rnorm(100, 10, 3), col3=c(rep("a", 50), rep("b", 50)))

co <- c()
for (i in levels(g$col3)){
    tmp <- cor(g[g[,"col3"]==i,"col1"], g[g[,"col3"]==i,"col2"])
    co <- c(co, tmp)
}
```

The `co` object contains the correlations for the dataframe in the order in which the levels appear in `levels(g[,"col3"])` which holds the categorical variable.

Answer (score 1):

For the toy-dataframe

```
g <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(100, 1, 1), 
                col2=rnorm(100, 10, 3), 
                col3=gl(2, 50),
                col4=gl(4, 25))
```

I think this is the most simple way to do this:

```
by(g, g$col3, function(x) cor(x$col1, x$col2))
```

And the same for several columns:

```
for (i in 3:ncol(g)) print(by(g, g[i], function(x) cor(x$col1, x$col2)))
```